# JQuery Event Binding with multiple dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm designing a website as part of my school's Virtual Enterprises class and need some help.

[Picture of Website Catalog for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOQIC.jpg)

Alright, the Order Now button `<button type="button" class="order-btn" id="order-btn">Order Now</button>` is dynamically added when the user clicks on one of the thumbnail images at the top of the site. I would like to have the large image and description/button, `og-fullimg` and `og-details` respectively, slide out of the viewport to the left when the user clicks the order button; they are also added dynamically. Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working.

JS

```
$(document).on('click', "#order-btn", function() {
    var order = $(this).parent(".og-details").attr("#order-btn");
    $("#og-fullimg").hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    $("#og-details").hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
});
```

I have included JQuery UI. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've already checked out [Event Binding on Dynamically Created Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements). Thank you for your help.

**Answer**

I forgot to add the easing for `.hide`. The code needed to make `og-fullimg` and `og-details` slide out of the viewport and for the order form, `order_form`, to slide in is below.

```
$(document).on('click', "#order-btn", function() {
    var order = $(this).parent(".og-details").attr("#order-btn");
    $("#og-fullimg").hide('slide', 'swing', '5000ms', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    $("#og-details").hide('slide', 'swing', '5000ms', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
    $("#order_form").toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

It took a while, but I figured it out eventually. Thanks to those who offered help.

Comment: what for you use $("#order-btn").on('click' twice? post fiddle here

Comment: may you add a html code ?